# Parsing a JSON object with Special characters in property key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file that looks something like this

```
{
    "samlp:Response": {
        "@attributes": {
            "xmlns:samlp": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol",
            "ID": "_482d7b9c-3e50-47cb-aa64-4e3655352c64",
            "Version": "2.0",
            "IssueInstant": "2019-06-27T17:02:47.711Z",
            "Destination": "https://jjds-sunrise--cqsupport--c.cs102.visual.force.com/apex/ResponseReceiver",
            "InResponseTo": "Azure_9849028456"
        }
    }
}
```

While trying to parse this JSON using the normal way i.e.

```
jsonObject.samlp:Response.@attributes.ID
```

where jsonObject is the object I created for this JSON. I am getting an error that says

> "unexpected token :"

. Am I doing it wrong or is there other way to parse this?

Comment: You can only use dot property access for property names that are valid identifiers, i.e. something you might use for a variable name. BTW, what you're doing isn't parsing, that has happened already. You're just trying to access an object's properties, the JSON part is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Consider the following:

```js
const jsonObject = {
  "samlp:Response": {
    "@attributes": {
      "xmlns:samlp": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol",
      "ID": "_482d7b9c-3e50-47cb-aa64-4e3655352c64",
      "Version": "2.0",
      "IssueInstant": "2019-06-27T17:02:47.711Z",
      "Destination": "https://jjds-sunrise--cqsupport--c.cs102.visual.force.com/apex/ResponseReceiver",
      "InResponseTo": "Azure_9849028456"
    }
  }
};


console.log(jsonObject["samlp:Response"]["@attributes"].ID);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error that says 
Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

Comment: @BonishKoirala please correct the JSON if there are any changes, the above code snippet works for the object you've provided in the question

Comment: Yeah got it. I was missing @ while trying to access value. Thank you very much.