# Access object key containing character :

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am pulling in reviews from iOS and the key they have has a : in the middle.

Like so: `im:rating: {attributes: {…}}`

Therefore, doing something like this is not working. `{entry.im:rating.label}`

How do I get the label from im:rating?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a JSON object with Special characters in property key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801172/parsing-a-json-object-with-special-characters-in-property-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: `entry['im:rating'].label`